# Openshift multiple set document root

Tags: php, openshift, redhat

i want to know,  can i have multiple sub domains in a gear?

I have 2 folders *backend* and *frontend*. Now I want to set doc root of ***www*** to be frontend and of ***admin*** be backend. Is it possible in openshift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't.

However you [can assign multiple aliases](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way) for an application, so you can set up an entry point for your app and load the desired one depends from the domain.

Comment: can you give some details on how can I load the desired app, based on domain? (alias)